# How to create customized Wix (3.0) widget to display HTML

Tags: html, widget

We want to display HTML page in our Wix-based installer, however with Wix 3.0, we didn't find any built-in HTML display widget. It seems creating customized/extended Wix widget for HTML display is the only way, so would like to ask for any clue, suggestion on customizing Wix widget.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that [EmbeddedUI](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_embeddedui.htm) is the only option for you here. But it's usually a lot of work...